# How to interpret length of None type object as zero?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I need to sort a list like below with increasing order of string length

```
lst = [None, 'abc', 'a', 'ab']
```

I'm using the below code to do that

```
lst.sort(key = lambda s: len(s))
```

But It's producing error

> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

As it is obvious `None` type object doesn't have any length. So, How can I modify the above code so that it starts interpreting length of `None` object as `0`.

Comment: `key = lambda s:s is not None and len(s)`

Comment: Why do you have `None`s in your list of strings? Are you sure you should have `None` instead of, say, an empty string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  a ternary operator:

```
lst.sort(key = lambda s: 0 if s is None else len(s))
```

`0` is returned when the item is `None` and `len(s)` for other items